# Non-Development IDE Netbeans Platform app with Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am attempting to create a NetBeans Platform Application int NetBeans 8.1 that can use Maven but a different Platform from the regular Development IDE. I've already added the platform I wish to use by going to Tools -> NetBeans Platforms -> Add Platform and it registered correctly with the IDE.

I can then use this platform to create a new NetBeans Platform application with the added platform as the base, but when I try to create a NetBeans Application by going under the Maven category only various versions of NetBeans are available. I'm still getting used to the environment but I'm pretty sure that it only shows these versions because it pulls those platforms from the repositories.

My question is there some way to create a Maven NetBeans Platform application with a third party Platform? If not possible to do that how would one go about adding the third party platform to a Maven NetBeans Platform application?

Comment: Rurouni could you format your post into paragraphs ? that would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

with maven based apps, you don't deal with the Tools -> NetBeans Platforms UI, you declare platform artifact versions in the maven pom files.